# React Routing error, adding an extra / to my URL

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router

This is the URL `http://localhost:3000/Constitution/`
It adds an extra `/` so when I click on another route it attaches to this route instead of sending me the another URL.

this is my router

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './routers/index';
import Contact from './routers/contact';
import About from './routers/about';
import Executives from './routers/executives';
import Constitution from './routers/constitution';



const AppRouter = () => {
    return <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true}/>
        <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact}/>
        <Route path="/About" component={About}/>
        <Route path="/Executives" component={Executives}/>
        <Route path="/Constitution" component={Constitution}/>
        
        </Switch>
        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    
}
export default AppRouter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :  `<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>`

Instead of this : `<Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true}/>`